# WCF Client Credential type = Username , when to use X509 certificate

Tags: wcf, wcf-security

I've been reading a lot about WCF Authentication using username and password. I am not getting my head round on when to use x509 certificate?

Could anyone please guide me to right direction on what scenario should I use X509 if using Username and Password?

1. Always
2. Depends (On what scenario?)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally always.

X.509 certificate ensures that channel is secured = only your service can read incoming user name and password (until certificate is stolen).

In case of WCF you need to configure certificate for message security because certificate for transport security (HTTPS) is configured outside of WCF on operating system level (either through netsh.exe or IIS).

If you don't use certificate you will not have secured channel and your user name and password will travel in network as a plain text - anybody who will get your transmitted packets will be able to use the stolen user name and password.

WCF by default doesn't allow sending user name and password over unsecured channel - you must create custom binding for that.

Comment: Thanks @Ladislav Mrnka, if we use HTTPs only. Doesn't it encrypt the username and password travelling through wire?

Comment: Also @Ladislav Mrnka, would you be able to clarify this "certificate for transport security (HTTPS) is configured outside of WCF on operation system level (either through netsh.exe or IIS)". If we have HTTPs configured doesn't message also get secured?

Comment: If you use HTTPS you already have certificate - HTTPS uses certificate for SSL. The message is secured if you are using HTTPS.